# Looking for two words

Tags: phrases, single-word-requests, terminology

I'm searching for two words or expressions.

The first word or expression means a situation in which there are too many items displayed on the screen, so that they cause a burden on the user and their rendering causes a burden on the CPU.

The second word is a verb that I can use to describe the deletion or filtering of some of the items in order to prevent this situation.

> In order to prevent `(word1)`, I need
>   to `(word2)` the items before sending
>   them to the display module. I keep a
>   list of `un(word2)ed` items and
>   generate a list of `(word2)ed`
>   items from it.

Perhaps something having to do with *spacing out*?

(I can't use the verb "filter" because it has a different meaning in the domain, and it seems to me that it doesn't convey the meaning precisely enough.)

Comment: Word1 can be "business" (or reword the sentence to use the word "busy"), but that is really only a connotation of burdenness for the user, not the CPU.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion:

word 1 - (visual) clutter

word 2 - you can use one of a number of words here, like *select*, *sift*, *pick out*, *screen out*, etc. but *filter* fits perfectly here and you will need to rephrase the sentence if you don't use it.

Comment: Clutter is perfect! If I want to use the verb "declutter", can I say that I'm generating a list of decluttered items?

Comment: @Ilya Yes I think 'decluttered' is pretty clear, but 'undecluttered' wouldn't be so I think you would need to rephrase your sentence a little.

Answer (score 2):

Options for word1:

- overloading
- excessive rendering
- slowdown
- memory shortages/problems

Options for word2 (also attempting to fit into the places used):

- prioritize / (low|high) priority / (un)displayed
- track / untracked / tracked
- police / (un)allowed / (un)allowed
- police / (un)approved / (un)approved
- check / (un)needed / (un)needed
- check / (un)wanted / (un)wanted
- check / (un)desired / (un)desired
- transition / (un)phased / (un)phased

The options here get pretty flexible, honestly. Just describe the behavior to a colleague and see what word pops out. Use that in the documentation.